# TikZ library creation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm wondering about the best (ie faster) way to create a new Tikz library.

Let's assume I have the components in a PDF/SVG/whatever vector graphic program. There is a possibility to directly convert from SVG to TikZ code (https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz). I could easily perform that task for each component I have. Then I'd have to add anchors / labels to the created shape by post-processing the obtained code.

For example with this shape:

[image: IGBT]

I would get the following code:

```
\definecolor{c010202}{RGB}{1,2,2}
\definecolor{cFFFFFF}{RGB}{255,255,255}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[draw=c010202,line join=round,line cap=round] (311.6780,393.3070) --
    (311.6780,404.6450) -- (297.5060,410.3140) -- (297.5060,410.3140);
  \path[draw=c010202,line join=round,line cap=round] (311.6780,450.0000) --
    (311.6780,438.6610) -- (297.5060,432.9920) -- (297.5060,432.9920);
  \path[draw=c010202,line join=round,line cap=rect,line width=1.600pt]
    (297.5050,404.6460) -- (297.5050,438.6620) -- (297.5050,438.6620);
  \path[draw=c010202] (294.6710,438.6610);
  \path[fill=c010202] (300.9860,436.6890) -- (302.5760,432.7140) .. controls
    (302.6780,432.4570) and (302.9690,432.3330) .. (303.2260,432.4350) .. controls
    (303.2750,432.4560) and (303.3220,432.4840) .. (303.3630,432.5180) --
    (308.5310,436.8910) .. controls (308.7420,437.0700) and (308.7670,437.3840) ..
    (308.5900,437.5950) .. controls (308.4880,437.7160) and (308.3360,437.7810) ..
    (308.1800,437.7720) -- (301.4200,437.3750) .. controls (301.1450,437.3590) and
    (300.9360,437.1220) .. (300.9510,436.8470) .. controls (300.9530,436.7930) and
    (300.9650,436.7400) .. (300.9860,436.6890) -- cycle;
  \path (300.9860,436.6890) -- (302.5760,432.7140) .. controls (302.6780,432.4570)
    and (302.9690,432.3330) .. (303.2260,432.4350) .. controls (303.2750,432.4560)
    and (303.3220,432.4840) .. (303.3630,432.5180) -- (308.5310,436.8910) ..
    controls (308.7420,437.0700) and (308.7670,437.3840) .. (308.5900,437.5950) ..
    controls (308.4880,437.7160) and (308.3360,437.7810) .. (308.1800,437.7720) --
    (301.4200,437.3750) .. controls (301.1450,437.3590) and (300.9360,437.1220) ..
    (300.9510,436.8470) .. controls (300.9530,436.7930) and (300.9650,436.7400) ..
    (300.9860,436.6890) -- cycle;
      \path[draw=c010202,line join=round,line cap=round] (294.6710,404.6460) --
        (294.6710,438.6610) -- (284.7500,438.6610);
          \path[fill=cFFFFFF] (284.7500,438.6610) circle (0.0424cm);
          \path[fill=c010202] (284.7500,436.9570) .. controls (285.6890,436.9570) and
            (286.4540,437.7220) .. (286.4540,438.6610) .. controls (286.4540,439.6000) and
            (285.6890,440.3650) .. (284.7500,440.3650) .. controls (283.8110,440.3650) and
            (283.0460,439.6000) .. (283.0460,438.6610) .. controls (283.0460,437.7220) and
            (283.8100,436.9570) .. (284.7500,436.9570) .. controls (285.6900,436.9570) and
            (283.8100,436.9570) .. (284.7500,436.9570) -- cycle(284.7500,439.9650) ..
            controls (285.4690,439.9650) and (286.0540,439.3810) .. (286.0540,438.6610) ..
            controls (286.0540,437.9420) and (285.4700,437.3570) .. (284.7500,437.3570) ..
            controls (284.0300,437.3570) and (283.4460,437.9420) .. (283.4460,438.6610) ..
            controls (283.4460,439.3810) and (284.0300,439.9650) .. (284.7500,439.9650) ..
            controls (285.4700,439.9650) and (284.0300,439.9650) .. (284.7500,439.9650) --
            cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

In order to use it easily I would have to add anchors (1 north, 1 south and 1 for gate), plus a label position.

Would this approach be the good way to do it or not?

The other way would be to start from any existing library and modify it to my needs.

Comment: Just to clarify: by 'best' you mean *just* 'faster to create (the library)'? I ask because 'best' may not coincide with 'fastest'. Also, I guess you mean 'fastest to create initially' and not necessarily 'most time-efficient overall'? Note that you probably will also want to eliminate the mixture of `pt` and `cm` else you will get odd effects if you use different font sizes. Do you really need curved lines in that shape?

Comment: @cfr yes I wouldn't like to loose too much time for doing it. The mixture of `cm` and `pt` is what came out of `svg2tikz`. I for example won't need ultra high flexibility for width/height etc of symbols. But if you think I'd gain in efficiency by doing it the other way around please let us know.